# Drag and drop with custom type identifier doesn't work

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm trying to achieve drag and drop on macOS with a custom type identifier to avoid collisions but it doesn't seem to work. First, here's a working example with a *public* and known identifier:

```swift
struct ReleaseView: View {
    let id: Int

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { _ in
            VStack(spacing: 16) {
                Image(nsImage: NSImage(named: NSImage.networkName)!)
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onDrag {
                        return NSItemProvider(item: "\(self.id)" as NSString, typeIdentifier: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.string.rawValue)
                    }

                DropZone()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DropZone: View {
    @State var isDragging = false

    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 4, dash: [8, 8]))
            .background(isDragging ? Color.secondary : Color.clear)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .onDrop(of: [NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.string.rawValue], isTargeted: self.$isDragging) { itemProvider in
                print(itemProvider)
                return true
            }
    }
}
```

In this example, you can drag the image above into the drop zone and it will print out the provider. Now, merely changing the `typeIdentifier` breaks everything.

```swift
static let sharedTypeIdentifier = "com.procrastin8.plzwork"

struct ReleaseView: View {
    // skipping the unchanged bits

                    .onDrag {
                        return NSItemProvider(item: "\(self.id)" as NSString, typeIdentifier: sharedTypeIdentifier)
                    }
}

struct DropZone: View {
    // skipping the unchanged bits

           .onDrop(of: [sharedTypeIdentifier], isTargeted: self.$isDragging) { itemProvider in
                print(itemProvider)
                return true
            }
}
```

Now this doesn't work. Using the same constant here, so it's not a string mismatch. Just yet another SwiftUI bug?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `typeIdentifier` in above is not just a unique string, it **must be UTI**.

If you want to use some custom-application-specifc UTI (think twice if you really need it), then you have to register one according to Apple rules, starting from

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
                <string>com.procrastin8.plzwork</string>
                ...
```

in app `Info.plist`

See details specifically in [Declaring New Uniform Type Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_declare/understand_utis_declare.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH204-SW1)

And wide collection in [Technical Q&A QA1796](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1796/_index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, you can add a type identifier through target project and it adds the UTI string automatically on the Info.plist, as explained on this [Raywenderlich article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/21679742-drag-and-drop-tutorial-for-swiftui#toc-anchor-015).

---

**Walkthrough**

1. Select the project on Project Navigator
2. Select the project target under "Targets" section
3. Select the "Info" tab
4. Expand "Exported Type Identifiers"
5. Click + to add a new UTI
6. Enter a description for the Description field
7. Enter your identifier for the Identifier field with the same value you used in your code
8. Under Conforms To enter public.data